# DateTime 7 days from now at 00:00

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to get the date 1 week before at 00:00:00 Here's what I've tried

```
$now             = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$start_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("-7 day"));
```

Output is `2017-04-11 11:33:52`  (UTC)

I tried to use

```
$start_date_time ->setTime(0, 0);
echo $start_date_time ->format('H:i:s');
```

But it's not datetime so I get an error. Any tips?

Comment: $start_date_time = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime("-7 day"));

Comment: Ah, I see now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).

Example:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(new \DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use **strtotime**

```
$start_date_time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days'));
```

or **DateTime** class

```
$date = new DateTime('7 days ago');
$date ->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$d=strtotime("-7 Days");
echo date("Y-m-d 00:00:00", $d);
```